# Conditionally expose REST resource

Tags: java, rest

I am a trying to write a sample REST service in Java using annotations instead of a deployment descriptor.

```
@ApplicationPath("/services")
public class RestApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        classes.add(Request.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

A sample Request class

```
@Path("sequence-numbers")
public class Request {
@POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createInstance(SnsConfig snsConfig, @Context final HttpServletResponse servletResponse,
                @Context final HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
    }
}
```

If classes.add(Request.class) is removed from the code the @Path("sequence-numbers") should not be exposed. But even when I comment out the classes.add statement, the post method is hit upon sending a request. Is my usage of the annotations wrong or is there something else that can possibly cause this?

Edit: I tried commenting out the entire getClasses method and still this works. I guess if no classes are specified under @ApplicationPath then all files are scanned for the presence of @Path. The reason I wanted to make use of getClasses was to check some application specific conditions and decide to either add or not add a class/@Path. Is there a way to expose a REST resource based on a condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. If you return an empty Set in your `getClasses()` method or you don't overwrite `getClasses()` (or `getSingletons()`) from `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`, then all paths will get scanned. If you return a non-empty set, than only the specified classes will be published.

Comment: Yes I was returning an empty set and that was the problem. I published the class corresponding to @ApplicationPath instead of returning an empty set and it works fine.